# What is the name of an object that instantiates a factory?

Tags: java, factory

I am generating instances of a pre-defined factory. Let's say the object I'm generating is a AppleFactory. AppleFactoryFactory seems awful. What is the common scheme for this kind of object?

Comment: FactoryFactory: For example: http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/server/RequestProcessorFactoryFactory

Comment: But that's what it is, a factory factory. Depending on the actual implementation it might be closer to a Builder.

Comment: Call it a MetaFactory. (AppleMetaFactory)

Answer (score 1):

AbstractFactory.

And you can generate whatever factory you want in it